# cucumber step duplication in diffrent stepdefs in java intellij

Tags: cucumber

I am working with cucumber, java. I have 10 test cases with different data from database but the steps in stepdefs file are same just minor changes required, so the given,when,then are also same just database tables for retrieving values is different. Is anybody know how  to work with this kind of scenario. I don't want to use data-table and excel sheets.I am using my SQL database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a place where developers post the code they are trying to make work. Please copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question.

Comment: Could you please post your steps which are the same and what would they execute in difference.

Comment: I have post my code below.

Answer (score 0):

```
Given User is open the browser for Fpl_tc1
And User is type the url for Fpl_tc1
When User is enter the valid username and password and click on SignIn button for Fpl_tc1
And User should be on the Request Manager page for Fpl_tc1
And User is navigating to programme manager to select Fee Payable Licensing for Fpl_tc1
And User is on Fee Payable Licensing page for editing parameters summary for Fpl_tc1
And User select the appropriate options for the Rights Granted panel for Fpl_tc1
And User fill the appropriate options for the Pricing Settings panel for Fpl_tc1
And search for individual titles for to set Fee Payable Licensing parameters for Fpl_tc1
And make a permissions request for Fpl_tc1
And ISBN/ISSN search for a title to get permission for Fpl_tc1
And fill the appropriate details of Select Content for the title of Fpl_tc1
And fill the appropriate options of Details of Content for the title of Fpl_tc1
And fill the appropriate details Select Planned Use for the title of Fpl_tc1
And fill the appropriate options Details of Usage for the title of Fpl_tc1
And set the details of Review Request for the title of Fpl_tc1
And check the status that request is sent for Fpl_tc1
And see the request is submitted as sent request for Fpl_tc1
Then set the default parameter settings for the title of Fpl_tc1
```

Comment: Above is my code where Fpl_tc1 is a testcase name we have up to 10 test case with the same sequence but the data need to proceed from database so everytime it is diffrent.